# Video Presets: Make selection of presets when viewing video; just like in Youtube (240p, 360p, etc)

Tags: 7, files

I'm using `video` and `video_presets`.

Two FLV presets with different video quality has been enabled through page `admin/config/media/video/presets`. One of them is the default with name `FLV`.

After submitted, the original file do converted to two FLV files, but when viewing the video, I see no option to enable a selection of presets for viewers. Viewers has no choice than watching videos of presets name `FLV`.

I want viewers can choose different quality like in Youtube, where viewers with slow internet connection can use 240p.

Any guide or hacks are greatly appreciated.